# Is there anything wrong with this IF statement? (C++)

Tags: c++, if-statement

Is there anything wrong with this IF statement in itself? Because it's currently true all the time and so I'm wandering if I've got my syntax wrong somewhere and it's throwing it out?

```
if (questinfo.targetitem == "coins" && questinfo.targetitemquant >= coins)
{
    cout << "You have enough coins to complete your task!" << endl;
    questactive = false;
}
```

`questinfo.targetitem` is a `string` (not array of chars).
`questinfo.targetitemquant` is an `int`.
`questactive` is a `bool`.
`coins` is an `int`.

`targetitemquant` is NEVER greater than `coins` at the moment but the statement always completes to true. Please tell me I've got my syntax wrong otherwise this just got far more difficult to pin down :(. Thanks.

Comment: print them before the if-statement or attach debugger and see what values they are assigned

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your syntax (that's the bad news, I suppose).

Comment: And if you can't see what's going wrong in your debugger, try stepping through the assembler for that line to see exactly what it's doing.

Comment: No, nothing wrong with the statement. It's the same as `(questinfo.targetitem == "coins") && (questinfo.targetitemquant >= coins)`You could simply place a few if statements before the line to see what goes wrong, `if (questinfo.targetitem == "coins") cout << "Debug:"<<questinfo.targetitem;`

Comment: "targetitemquant is NEVER greater than coins" but the test will pass if it **equals** coins as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the syntax is wrong the compiler will produce an error, so that way you will know anyway.

If it is compiling but not working as you expect then it's going to be a logic error, in which case you can use a debugger to work out why.

It doesn't seem to be a syntax error, so I would suggest debugging it.

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically the above code is correct, hence it compiles.
I assume that you have thoroughly debbuged you code & whatever you are saying is true, the possibility i see here is,,,
May be you are storing a value that is greater than `signed int`.
Hence, causing an overflow representing a negative value..
If targetitemquant is a non negative value, try using `unsigned int` data type..