# Attempt to extract a component of a value that is not a structure. c++

Tags: c++, debugging, if-statement, struct

Off the back of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012562/is-there-anything-wrong-with-this-if-statement-c/22012920) I went and did my first debug (n00b) and got the error: `Attempt to extract a component of a value that is not a structure.` 
What does this mean and what are the implications for my code?

```
if (questinfo.targetitem == "coins" && questinfo.targetitemquant >= coins)
{
    cout << "You have enough coins to complete your task!" << endl;
    questactive = false;
}
```

The struct definition, as requested, is as follows:

```
struct questdata{
  int ID;
  string targetitem;
  int targetitemquant;
  string questgiver;
  string questdesc;
};
questdata questinfo;
```

and the members' values are assigned from an array like so:

```
questinfo.ID  = atoi(queststuff[0].c_str());
questinfo.targetitem  = queststuff[1];
questinfo.targetitemquant  = atoi(queststuff[2].c_str());
questinfo.questgiver  = queststuff[3];
questinfo.questdesc = queststuff[4];
```

I thought it could be that `ID` and `targetitemquant` were treated as c strings but the error occurs on `targetitem` and `targetitemquant`.

Comment: I guess it's the *debugger* and not the compiler that give you this message? If so, what did you do in the debugger to get this message?

Comment: which debugger? What did you type in to the debugger? What point were you at in the code?

Comment: Without knowing anything about these variables whatsoever, I couldn't possibly tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having spent HOURS on this... it was a VERY simple logic error. :@

```
if (questinfo.targetitem == "coins" && questinfo.targetitemquant >= coins)
```

should have been

```
if (questinfo.targetitem == "coins" && questinfo.targetitemquant <= coins)
```

note the difference in > and <.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear if you are able to compile the code and are debugging in a debugger that caused this error or by debug you mean first compile?

If this is a debug time issue, posting debugger info, context at which this error appears is useful. Most likely you have same named variable that is not a structure in the context of this error.

Answer (score -1):

`questinfo.targetitem == "coins"` is comparing the structure member against a string - which is not allowed...
It would be helpful to see the definition on the `questinfo` structure.

Comment: targeritem is string type you will find that if you go through the link he provided...if its string comparision is valid then.

Comment: added the definition into the question

Comment: Added into the question :)

Comment: Why have I been voted down? I tried to answer the question based on incomplete information (before the struct had been added) - seems unfair.

QUOTE: "I thought it could be that ID and targetitemquant were treated as c strings" 
Why would this be the case? you have declared both as INT's.

Since we still don't know was types "coins" is, I am going to take a stab in the dark and assume it's either a string, a variable which is a structure - in which case you are try to compare an integer against a more complex type which is why you are getting the error message.
PS... Which is the error line?